# How do I compute facets/aggregations for the top n documents, with pagination in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, pagination, faceted-search

Suppose I have an index for cars on a dealer's car lot. Each document resembles the following:

```
{
  color: 'red',
  model_year: '2015',
  date_added: '2015-07-20'
}
```

Suppose I have a million cars.

Suppose I want to present a view of the most recently added 1000 cars, along with facets over those 1000 cars.

I could just use `from` and `size` to paginate the results up to a fixed limit of 1000, but in doing so the totals and facets on `model_year` and `color` (i.e. aggregations) I get back from Elasticsearch aren't right--they're over the entire matched set.

How do I limit my search to *the most recently added 1000 documents* for pagination *and* aggregation?

Comment: Can you show the query you're using?

Comment: @Val- the query part isn't that interesting and could even be a match-all. e.g. `{
  "sort": {
    "date_added": {
      "order": "desc"
    }
  }
}`

Comment: Pagination is [not possible](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/4915) for the result of an aggregation.

Comment: @AndreiStefan given my relatively small set maybe I should just always retrieve 200 docs and do pagination outside of Elasticsearch? Then maybe all I need is a way to scope the aggregation to the top N docs (no `from` needed then)--is that possible?

Comment: Is [top_hits aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) the feature you are looking for?

Comment: Hmmm, now I'm not so sure. Does top_hits more limit individual buckets rather than the set of documents they gather aggregations for?

Answer (score 1):

As you probably saw in the documentation, the aggregations are performed on the scope of the query itself. If no query is given, the aggregations are performed on a `match_all` list of results. Even if you would use `size` at the query level, it will still not give you what you need because `size` is just a way of **returning a set** of documents from all the documents the query matched. Aggregations operate on what the query matches.

This feature request is not new and has been [asked for before](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/2040) some time ago.

In 1.7 there is no straight forward solution. Maybe you can use the [limit filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-limit-filter.html) or [terminate_after](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html) in-body request parameter, but this will not return the documents that were, also, sorted. This will give you the **first** `terminate_after` number of docs that matched the query and this number is per shard. This is not performed after the sorting has been applied.

In ES 2.0 there is, also, the [sampler aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/search-aggregations-bucket-sampler-aggregation.html) which works more or less the same way as the `terminate_after` is working, but this one takes into consideration the score of the documents to be considered from each shard. In case you just sort after `date_added` and the query is just a `match_all` all the documents will have the same score and it will be returning an irrelevant set of documents.

In conclusion:

- there is no good solution for this, there are workarounds with number of docs per shard. So, if you want 1000 cars, then you need to take this number divide it by the number of primary shards, use it in `sampler` aggregation or with `terminate_after` and get a set of documents
- my suggestion is to **use a query to limit the number of documents (cars) by a different criteria** instead. For example, show (and aggregate) the cars in the last 30 days or something similar. Meaning, the criteria should be included in the query itself, so that the resulting set of documents to be the one you want it aggregated. Applying aggregations to a certain number of documents, after they have been sorted, is not easy.